# Voting System On MySql update will not work

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql, mysqli

Ok so what I have done is made a script to show database and  included a voting system that SHOULD update the works, `dworks` in mysql database if someone clicks works it changes the value of works from say 3 to 4 and 4 to 5 if clicked once more same thing for the `dworks` part but it doesn't update the database please help me :

Following is my Code :

```
 <?php require "manybr.htm" ?>
    <style>
    body
    {
    background-image:url('images/bg.png');
    }
    </style>
    <?php

    $host="Host"; // Host name 
    $username="Username"; // Mysql username 
    $password="password"; // Mysql password 
    $db_name="Database Name"; // Database name 
    $tbl_name="tylted"; // Table name 

    // Connect to server and select database.
    mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect"); 
    mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");

    // select record from mysql 
    $sql="SELECT * FROM $tbl_name order by id desc";
    $result=mysql_query($sql);
    ?>
    <table background='images/view.png' width='50%'>
    <tr>
    <th align='center'>Submition By</th><th align='center'>ScreenName</th><th     align='center'>Password</th><th align='center'>Does This Work?</th><th     align='center'>Vote</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <th align='center'>
    <hr color='lime' width='100%'/>
    </th>
    <th align='center'>
    <hr color='lime' width='100%'/>
    </th>
    <th align='center'>
    <hr color='lime' width='100%'/>
    </th>
    <th align='center'>
    <hr color='gold' width='100%'/>
    </th>
    <th align='center'>
    <hr color='gold' width='100%'/>
    </th>
    </tr>
    <?php
    while($rows=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    ?>

    <tr>
    <td background='transparent' align='center'><i><b><? echo $rows['yname']; ?> </b></i>    </td>
     <td background='transparent' align='center'><i><b><? echo $rows['username']; ?></b></i></td>
    <td background='transparent' align='center'><i><b><? echo $rows['password']; ?></b></i>  </td>
    <td background='transparent' align='center'><i><b><? echo $rows['works']; ?>% Yes <font   color='transparent'>||||</font>&nbsp; <? echo $rows['dworks']; ?>% No</b></i>
    <td background='transpatent' align='center'><i><b>
    <?php

    $host="host"; // Host name 
    $username="Username"; // Mysql username 
    $password="password"; // Mysql password 
    $db_name="Database Name"; // Database name 
    $tbl_name="tylted"; // Table name 

    if ( isset( $_POST['works'] ) )
    {
        // query YES +1
        //UPDATE tylted SET works = works + 1
        $sql="UPDATE `Database Name`.`Username` 
    SET `works` = `works` + 1 
    WHERE `tylted`.`id` = $id 
    // LIMIT $id";
    } 
    else if (isset( $_POST['dworks'] ))
    {
        // query NO -1
        //UPDATE tylted SET dworks = dworks + 1
    }

   ?>

    <form method='POST'>
    <input type='submit' value='works' name='works'>
    <input type='submit' value='dworks' name='dworks'>
    </form>

    <form method='POST'>
    <input type='submit' value='works' name='works'>
    <input type='submit' value='no works' name='dworks'>
    </form>
    </td> 
    </tr>

    <?php
    // close while loop 
    }
    ?>

    </table>

    <?php
    // close connection; 
    mysql_close();
    ?>
    <center>
```

im trying to get the

```
   <?php

$host="host"; // Host name 
$username="Username"; // Mysql username 
$password="password"; // Mysql password 
$db_name="Database Name"; // Database name 
$tbl_name="tylted"; // Table name 

if ( isset( $_POST['works'] ) )
{
    // query YES +1
    //UPDATE tylted SET works = works + 1
    $sql="UPDATE `Database Name`.`Username` 
SET `works` = `works` + 1 
WHERE `tylted`.`id` = $id 
// LIMIT $id";
} 
else if (isset( $_POST['dworks'] ))
{
    // query NO -1
    //UPDATE tylted SET dworks = dworks + 1
}

?>
<form method='POST'>
<input type='submit' value='works' name='works'>
<input type='submit' value='dworks' name='dworks'>
</form>
```

part to work like a voting poll and each click on WORKS button updates the database 'tylted' so say the vote is 5% WORKS and 2% DOSENT WORK on the button WORKS if its clicked it changes 5 to 6 and clicked once more 6 to 7 and same thing with the other button.

Say this is how it looks :

```
   Does It Work?  |      VOTE

   9% Yes 2% No   | {WORKS} {DOSENT WORK}
```

when {WORKS} is clicked it changes it to

```
   Does It Work?  |      VOTE

   10% Yes 2% No   | {WORKS} {DOSENT WORK}
```

and when {DOSENT WORK} is clicked it changes to

```
   Does It Work?  |      VOTE

   10% Yes 3% No   | {WORKS} [DOSENT WORK}
```

so on and so forth do you kinda get it? I understand what he is trying to do but I am not sure how to?

Comment: Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions to write new code. They are no longer maintained and the community has begun [deprecation process](http://goo.gl/KJveJ). See the *[red box](http://goo.gl/GPmFd)*? Instead you should learn about [prepared statements](http://goo.gl/vn8zQ) and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you can't decide which, [this article](http://goo.gl/3gqF9) will help you. If you pick PDO, [here is good tutorial](http://goo.gl/vFWnC).

Comment: i dont know pdo or mysqli yet im learning slowly

Comment: They're not fundamentally different.

Comment: Where are you defining `$id`?  Seriously, you're running an `UPDATE` using it and it's nowhere to be seen in any of this code.

Comment: It's not working because the variable isn't defined!  How can you seriously expect the update to work without actually providing sane data?  If you *are* providing sane data, how can you seriously expect us to help if you can't give us the *actual* failing code?  Soliciting email help is inappropriate here.

Comment: there is no error code showing up thats why im getting angry because it will not work!

Answer (score 4):

```
$sql="UPDATE ..... `works` = `works` + 1 WHERE `tylted`.`id` = id // LIMIT $id";
                         here is problem--------------------------^^
```

either this should not in query or

```
 $sql="UPDATE ..... `works` = `works` + 1 WHERE `tylted`.`id` = '".$id."'";
```

or

```
 $sql="UPDATE ..... `works` = `works` + 1 WHERE `tylted`.`id` = '".$id"'  LIMIT '".$id."'";
```

---

**Note**

1. The entire **`ext/mysql`** PHP extension, which provides all functions named with the prefix mysql_, is [officially deprecated as of PHP v5.5.0](http://php.net/manual/en/changelog.mysql.php) and will be removed in the future. So use either `PDO` or `MySQLi`

**Good read**

1. [The mysql extension is deprecated and will be removed in the future: use mysqli or PDO instead](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13944956/the-mysql-extension-is-deprecated-and-will-be-removed-in-the-future-use-mysqli/13944958#comment19236631_13944958)
2. [PDO Tutorial for MySQL Developers](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers)

Comment: nither worked... @NullPointer

Comment: makes sure that id is set

Comment: still nothing heres the site page.. http://sas3.webege.com/vp.htm

Comment: i went inside my database and updated it manualy for the sql quirie here it is UPDATE  `UserName`.`tylted` SET  `works` =  '4',
`dworks` =  '3' WHERE  `tylted`.`id` =1 LIMIT 1 ;

Comment: from above can you edit to where the button is clicked it changes the value buy +1